# Ошибка при написании unit-tests в Django

Tags: python, django, юнит-тесты, django-rest-framework, pytest

вот мои тесты:

```
from unittest import TestCase
import django
from django.test import Client
from django.conf import settings
import os

settings.configure(
    DEBUG=True,
    ROOT_URLCONF='backend.urls',
    SECRET_KEY='django-insecure-b96pez8nzn!3z+++bc2+0%j2t3qf9xhmj=q7ob-4(^y(jjyr!u',
)

# django.setup()


class TestViews(TestCase):

    def test_main_page_GET(self):
        client = Client()
        response = client.get('registration/')

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        # self.assertTemplateNotUsed(response, 'quiz_core_app/main_page.html')

    def test_index(self):
        client = Client()
        resp = client.get('/')

        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
```

Очень тяжелая для меня ошибка, мучаюсь уже 3 день и все никак не могу решить, на просторах интернета крайне мало информации об этом, из всего этого выходит две ошибки, первая, если раскомментировать django.setup():

```
 raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

а вот вторая если оставить его в комментариях:

```
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Вот еще как выглядят мои установленные приложения в settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'quiz_core_app.apps.QuizCoreAppConfig',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'django_filters',
    'corsheaders',
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю проблему, аргументы, которые не были переданы в `settings.configure`, будут инициализированы значениями по умолчанию (см. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/settings/#using-settings-without-setting-django-settings-module), поэтому список INSTALLED_APPS будет пустой. Нужно или передать INSTALLED_APPS в `settings.configure`, или добавить настройки по умолчанию (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/settings/#custom-default-settings)